# action handling thru different frames

Tags: java, swing, action

I have a design problem that seems somewhat basic, but I am struggling to find an adequate solution as I don't have much experience in OO design.

I have a system that has got a lot of frames in which the user needs to identify the enterprise/corporation. One way of doing so is clicking on a button which will open a second frame which enables the user to select the company. After the selection has been made, the corporation's code and name should be initialized in textfields on the original frame.

I don't think its a good design choice to duplicate the action code in every single frame that needs the company identification. Still, I don't see how I would be able to create a single `ActionListener` (or `javax.swing.Action`) without a reference to the frame which triggered the action because I wouldn't be able to initialize the textfields (or would I?).

My first idea was to implement a common interface for all frames which would need the search service with a single method like `setCorporation(Corporation corporation)`. That way, when I create an `ActionListener`, I would pass a reference of an instance of a frame which implemented the interface.

The problem is that this solution would create double references (`addActionListener(new SearchAction(this))`) and I would have to implement an interface for every problem alike (like searching clients).

What's the best approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: Your system should use one and only one JFrame.  You can have multiple JPanels in a JFrame.  You can also use JDialogs or JOptionPanes to gather additional information.  Read through Oracle's guide to creating a GUI.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc, thank you for taking your time to help me, I really appreciate it. Anyway, its a complex system for enterprise management, which should have a lot of forms. It surely could be done with a single frame and lots and lots of internal frames. But I think the problem would still persist. I need textfields initialized on the different internal frames, panels or anything like that. There a lot of completely different processes that need this information.

Comment: You create a GUI data model to hold the information processed in various JPanels and JDialogs.  The instance of this data model is passed to all of the GUI view classes.

Comment: Once more, I thank you my friend. When you say a data model you mean initialize the corporation once and pass it to all the internal frames which sould display it? If so, I need to identificate the coporation for every internal frame as the user could create a document for a corporation, close the internal frame and then create a payable for a different corporation on another internal frame.

Comment: Based on your comment, the GUI data model would have classes for a corporation, a document, and a payable.  Anything your GUI can produce needs to be stored in the data model.

Comment: Gilbert, once more, thanks for the help and for the patience. I am a litte confused, maybe because english is not my first language and Im not undersanting it correctly. Anyway, when you say data model are you talking about the domain? If so, I have classes for all of those (corporation, document, payabl, etc). But my doubt and confusion still remains, my search initialize a corporation object that should be passed to the original internal frame that called it. The problem is that many internal frames have to call it to initialize the corporation object, and I have no commom way to do so   .

Comment: This isn't the place for an extended discussion about the philosophy of coding a GUI.  I passed along what I could, but until you read the Oracle guide I liked to earlier, we're not even using the same English words for the same concepts.